# Magento 2: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, php, error

I followed the Magento dev docs per below:

> If you add a new .html template, and then edit it, the changes will
>   not apply until you do the following: delete all files in the
>   pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessing directories, then
>   reload the pages. You can delete the files manually or run the grunt
>   clean: command in CLI. For details about using Grunt in
>   Magento see Installing and configuring Grunt.

However now in developer mode set via htaccess I get Internal Server Error 500 across site and admin urls. Is that a caching issue if its looking for the cleared files to render?

Comment: check your error log.

Comment: internal server 500 comes due to file permission, just give 755 to folder and 644 to file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in developer mode the files are automatically generated when requested and not found. So this should not be a Problem.

When facing a 500 error the first thing you should do is search for your webserver error log.

When running on apache it can mostly be found in one of these 2 locations:

> /var/log/httpd/ -> centos, archlinux ...
>
> /var/log/apache2/ -> debian, ubuntu ...

Comment: Nginx server we can find under `/var/log/nginx`

Answer (score 4):

Try to run following command in the Magento root
and before running this command give the full permissions to the installation directory

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Internal Server Error!! Magento 2.2.2 Very Important !! especially for WAMPserver in windows10

1. Please make sure that LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so is loaded from httpd.conf, This bug cause Internal Server Error of Magento 2.2.2
   and if following setting got "#" , pls remove "#"

LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

2. create a new folder and name it "static" after /pub/
   looks like this: http://localhost/magento222/pub/static/
   right click the "static" folder and click property to make sure if it is writable.
3. delete your old mysql database for magento222 and create a new one to make a clean and safe installation.

P.S.: Ver. 2.2.2 is not a stable version.

Answer (score 2):

Please check .htaccess first.possibility of module not enabled. Because i faced this issue because of mod_version module so I enabled it from apache and now it's working.

You can check also with replacing your .htaccess file Or renamed it to confirm issue of .htaccess file.

Comment: i have replace .htaccess file and resolved issue  thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Magento 2.2.4. Then first go to Apache log directory and

```
[Wed May 30 00:58:17.857269 2018] [core:alert] [pid 7184:tid 1244] [client 127.0.0.1:65528] C:/Creation/wamp64/www/m2version/ms-live-version/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 30 00:58:42.568180 2018] [core:alert] [pid 7184:tid 1248] [client 127.0.0.1:49165] C:/Creation/wamp64/www/m2version/ms-live-version/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 30 00:59:01.667499 2018] [core:alert] [pid 7184:tid 1252] [client 127.0.0.1:49169] C:/Creation/wamp64/www/m2version/ms-live-version/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 30 01:00:04.655715 2018] [core:alert] [pid 7184:tid 1272] [client 127.0.0.1:49174] C:/Creation/wamp64/www/m2version/ms-live-version/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Wed May 30 01:00:35.151803 2018] [core:alert] [pid 7184:tid 1272] [client 127.0.0.1:49201] C:/Creation/wamp64/www/m2version/ms-live-version/.htaccess: Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

According to the log, the main problem is a .htaccess file. I don't know the exact reason but following code remove from the .htaccess file is working.

Remove file tag code.

```
<Files composer.json>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files composer.lock>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files .gitignore>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files .htaccess.sample>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files .php_cs.dist>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files .travis.yml>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files CHANGELOG.md>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files COPYING.txt>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files Gruntfile.js>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files LICENSE.txt>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files nginx.conf.sample>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files package.json>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files php.ini.sample>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files README.md>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files auth.json>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
<Files magento_umask>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

Note : I don't know there may problem in future or not. But it's help me.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue by changing file permission of index.php

> 664 to 644

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same situation in morning but thanks to @david answer.

After a bit research of log directory of Apache, I came to know about that apache don't have permission to read **app/etc/** folder.

So, after giving permission all working fine.

Comment: Please tell me the path .

Comment: If you are on Linux environment then it will be usually /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd/

Answer (score 1):

1. It could also be because of wrong file permissions.
2. Make sure that you CHMOD to `"user":"group" "magento install DIR"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is due to the ownership issues. I was using ubuntu os so I used the following the command to correct ownership.

`sudo useradd magento`

Now associate this magento user to the web server’s user group. In ubuntu it is by default www-data

`sudo usermod -g www-data magento`

Now navigate the Magento project directory in the terminal and run following commands.

`sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;`
`sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;`
`sudo chown -R magento:www-data .` 
`sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`

Once these commands run successfully then magento user have all required permission whatever Magento setup needed.

Restart the apache server by the following command

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: your code cost me to loose ownership of my publiv_html folder and everthin inside,
anyone that has the issue should run this command to revert chanes: for i  in `cat /etc/trueuserdomains | awk '{print $2}'`
 > do
 > chown $i.$i /home/$i -R;
 > chown $i.mail /home/$i/etc -R;
 > chown $i.nobody /home/$i/public_html;
 > chmod 750 /home/$i/public_html;
 > done;

Comment: @TheDeadGuy, it was a too old comment. I apologized for it. Now I have edited my answer please try with this.

Comment: you are forgiven ;)

Answer (score 0):

seems need only to index.php

show php errors [Show PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1266559)

and after can fix

in my case - was permission for dirs

Answer (score 0):

Struggled for an hour and finally issue got resolved after removing the proxy settings. Whoever facing this issue, check your proxy setting.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by giving proper file permissions to magento root folder

Answer (score 0):

It is a very sophisticated issue.

Much possible reason can happen for this. Better than going randomly, debug the issue.

if you are using apache2 to go to **/var/log/apache2** and you will found error.log, other there you will found a specific reason why this is happening. And solved it by a search over the internet.

**Possible Problem:**

- If you copy files and database from existing site and put directoly on the new server then there may some copatibilty issue, for this upload a freash copy and try to install it, you will found what is missing
- In the new Magento version, there is a special folder called **generated**. That must be write permission.
- Another main reason is overall file permission. Be sure **var, generated, vendor, app/etc, pub/media & pub/static** have proper write access.