# Css and Js not loading from the static and media Magento 2

Tags: magento2, js-css

I put my code on server and when I deployed it i get the error Internal server 500 so I `deleted the .htaccess` from the root of directory but `css and js` not loading and run deploy the update the `di:compile` and put 777 /var /generated pub/media and pub/static when i see the folder under pub/static /frontend .fr_FR/theme/it is empty same for media no wysiwyg and there are some folder related to theme missing on server. In local everything is working fine.

Comment: Please check the file permission where you put your new code. if you are in production mode then please run static content deploy, then give permission 777 to pub ,var, generated

Comment: i really did that but still same error

Comment: one queston when i delete the .htaccess i find the Fo without css and js else if i keep it i get the intenal server error 500

Comment: There probably two reasons for that. 1. some PHP module is lot loading or some misconfiguration 2. File permission. You may try solutions form this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100896/magento-2-500-internal-server-error, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Run below command step by step and check.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> Php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help!